# How to fix a Bootloop Nexus 5X that is bootloader locked?

Tags: boot-loop, nexus-5x, 8.0-oreo

I have a nexus 5x that is boot looping after the android 8 update. My bootloader is locked as I won't be able to install any custom image firmware. My concern is keeping my data in tact, and even if I was able to unlock my bootloader, I'd have to wipe my entire device which is something I dont want to do.

How can I fix my bootlooping Nexus 5x without losing my data?

Comment: For those looking to fix it with unlocked bootloader: https://www.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x-bootloop-fix-boot-phone/  and --- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hm-bVsgp8Ps